# Restricted by CORS policy even after enabling CORS on Express and Express gateway

Tags: node.js, reactjs, cors, microservices, express-gateway

I'm using `Express Gateway` to proxy my microservices. I'm hitting the gateway from my `react` app with `Axios`. However, the call gets restricted by the `CORS Policy`. I have enabled CORS in the express gateway and also on my authentication service. I followed the official documentation to enable the CORS from this [link](https://www.express-gateway.io/docs/policies/cors/) for Express Gateway and this [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors) for authentication service(Express App). Here is how I have the code.

Express Gateway config.yml

```
policies:
  - log
  - proxy
  - jwt
  - rate-limit
  - request-transformer
  - cors

pipelines:
  authPipeline: 
    apiEndpoints: 
      - auth
    policies: 
      -
        cors:
          -
            action:
              origin: '*'
              methods: 'HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE'
              allowedHeaders: ['Content-Type', 'Authorization']
      - 
        log: 
          action:
            message: 'auth ${req.method}'
      - 
        proxy:
          action: 
            serviceEndpoint: di
```

Authentication Service app.js

```
const cors = require('cors');
// Enabling CORS
const corsOptions = {
  origin: '*',
  methods: ['POST', 'GET', 'PATCH', 'DELETE'],
  allowedHeaders: ['Content-Type', 'Authorization']
}
app.use(cors(corsOptions));
```

The Headers I get back from the server when I try with Insomnia (a client like Postman) can be seen in the below picture.

[image: The Headers I get from the server]

I get this error in the browser console.

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/v1/users/login' from 
origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to 
preflight request doesnt pass access control check: No 'Access-Control- 
Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

I'm not sure what I'm missing. Please let me know if you need anything else, I'd be quick to provide. Each and every attempt that tries to explain what's wrong with my case is really appreciated.

EDIT: Adding the API call snippet

```
const config = {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
  };
const body = JSON.stringify({ email, password });
const res = await axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/v1/users/login', body, config);
```

Comment: Why do you want to use origin: ‘*’?

Comment: Well, I just wanted it to work irrespective of the origin. That's why I used it. @JamesMcLeod

Comment: But don’t you know the set of possible origins a priori? This seems to defeat the purpose of CORS. Can you try it with a specific value and see if it works?

Comment: @JamesMcLeod I tried after keeping only my react server's port. Still I get the same error.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors#enabling-cors-pre-flight

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your "methods" definition is incorrect. It needs to be in the form of a YAML array:

```
methods: [ "HEAD", "PUT", "PATCH", "POST", "DELETE" ]
```

Or

```
methods:
- "HEAD"
- "PUT"
- "PATCH"
- "POST"
- "DELETE"
```

Or

```
methods:
- HEAD
- PUT
- PATCH
- POST
- DELETE
```

Everything else looks okay, although you may want to add "origin" to the list of allowedHeaders.

**Update**
I have done some further testing on this, using this mini express server, then run the API gateway and server on Docker (with appropriate hostname changes in gateway.config.yml), and everything works as I expect with testing via curl from localhost and also from the browser.

```
var express = require('express')
var app = express()

// Enabling CORS
const cors = require('cors');
const corsOptions = {
  origin: '*',
  methods: ['POST', 'GET', 'PATCH', 'DELETE'],
  allowedHeaders: ['Content-Type', 'Authorization']
}
app.use(cors(corsOptions));

function addPath(path) {
  app.use(path, function(req, res, next) {
    const response = `Hello from ${req.method} ${path}`;
    console.log(response);
    res.send(response);
  });
}

addPath('/api/v1/users/*');
addPath('/api/v1/*');

const port = 5000;
app.listen(port, function () {
  console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}`)
})
```

The only other thing I can suggest is to add another log message *before* the cors policy entry in gateway.config.yml like this:

-
log:
action:
message: "incoming (auth): ${req.method} ${req.path} requesting IP: ${req.ip} origin ${req.headers.origin}"

and check the value of origin. If it is not undefined, try adding the following response-transformer before the proxy policy (adding response-transformer to the list of available policies, of course). I have had to do this once or twice but I forget the circumstances where it was necessary, so this is a shot in the dark.

```
  - response-transformer:
    - condition:
        name: expression
        expression: 'typeof req.headers.origin !== "undefined" && req.headers.origin === "http://localhost"'
      action:
        headers:
          add:
            access-control-allow-origin: '"http://localhost"'
```

Comment: I get the same error again and again, even after I have changed the values to `origin: 'http://localhost:3000/'` `methods: ["HEAD", "PUT", "PATCH", "POST", "DELETE"]` `allowedHeaders: ["Content-Type", "Authorization"]`.
I will update the question by adding the snippet of how I'm calling the API. Please have a look.

Comment: are all other server endpoints working? can it be a browser issue? did you try curl? if you have any simple GET API that you can hit from the browser directly, try that from browser address bar

Comment: I tried hitting the gateway from browser's address bar with a simple GET and it works. but when I try to call the same endpoint from within the react it again throws same error. I'm not sure what could've gone wrong. The other server endpoints are working fine. @PranayNailwal

Comment: @VenkateshDharavath, it looks from your code snippet as if you are posting instead of getting; without seeing the rest of the config file, we can't really help with this. Can you hit it using curl, with both GET and POST and see if either / both work?

Comment: @JamesMcLeod, I thoroughly tested the API through gateway. It works fine with Insomnia(tool like postman). Here is the [gateway.config.yml](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Xz2uPYv5J_U6IXSIiSz3U_DWaA5MGjGr/view?usp=sharing) link for your reference.

Comment: @VenkateshDharavath I have updated my answer with the results of my own tests. I fear I cannot help any further.

Comment: Well, I have committed a silly mistake which took a long time to debug. I simply put the `origin: 'http://localhost:3000\'` instead of `origin: 'http://localhost:3000'`. The trailing slash is what created the problem. I have accepted this answer as it helped me in debugging. Thanks @JamesMcLeod.

Answer (score 0):

if you have methods in auth apiEndpoints then removed methods from apiEndpoints: auth
----methods: 'GET,POST,PUT' ----
and it worked for me..